# How do I respond to a buffer/stack overflow

Tags: security

From a security perspective, how do I respond if I have discovered a stack overflow?

Comment: If a program is exploited and code execution privileges are gained then that should not compromise security, applications should be run with the least amount of privileges possible. What do you mean "from a security perspective"?

Comment: @DevinM maybe there is a "business perspective"

Comment: @Joseph Well it would help if we understood his position, is he a programmer looking for advice on how to fix the issue, A system administrator looking through logs or some other role? All those people have a different job and need to respond likewise.

Comment: @David M: we don't know what the "least amount of privileges" is for the application in question, but chances are that it's a real superset of what single objects (users, documents, ...) are allowed to do within the application. So usually we face a real privilege escalation here, even if we assume that we live in an utopic world like the one you describe, where everyone uses perfect, fine-grained, correctly configured access control for everything.

Answer (score 3):

1. Disable.

   Take the service offline. This will help prevent further damage.
2. Verify.

   Make sure that the issue is reproducible.
3. Find.

   Inspect the code to see what the cause is.
4. Repair.

   Effect the changes required to ensure that the issue does not happen again due to the same cause.